# Multiple definition of vector in header file error c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, header-files

### ERROR WHICH I GOT

`Multiple defintion of veh`

##### Main.cpp

```
int main()
  {
    int choice;
    char ans;
   // string filen;
    system ( "cls" ) ;
    std::cout<<"ENTER FILE NAME with Extenstion:";
    std::cin>>filen;
    veh.at(i).vehcileLoad();
```

##### car.h

```
class vehicle
{
    public:
        vehicle();
        virtual ~vehicle();
        void addVehicle();
        void deleteVehicle();
        void printvehicle(vehicle v);
        void show();
        void showleft();
        void vehcileLoad();

    protected:

    private:
    std::string pltno;
    date dt;
    lime arrive;
    lime departure;
};
std::vector<vehicle> veh(100);
std::vector<vehicle> vehleft(100);
std::fstream file;
std::string filen;
#endif // VEHICLE_H
```

##### Implementation FILE

The file contains all functions of the vehicle such as add vehcile etc A bit too long to include it but i did not redfine it there

### What i Tried

I have tried using `Extern` But it did not work I tried adding them to the implementation file and main file it did not work either

```
std::vector<vehicle> veh(100);
std::vector<vehicle> vehleft(100);
std::fstream file;
std::string filen;
```

These lines above are the ones which are getting the multiple definition of ... issue even though i only declared it in the header file how can i fix this issue please help me im stuck??

Comment: Don't *define* variables in header files, only *declare* them. As in `extern std::vector<vehicle> veh;` Do the definition (`std::vector<vehicle> veh(100);`) in a single source file.

Comment: Even better: Don't use global variables at all! Define locally inside functions, and pass as arguments to the functions that needs them.

Comment: *even though i only declared it in the header file* - `#include` is very simple directive, it copies and pastes file content verbatim where `include` was. So even though you define the variables in one header file, by `include`'ing it in two source files, you create one definition of each variable in each source file, and there should be only one definition of each variable in the whole program.